# How i can perform barcode scanner in offline mode with using in camera as it can scan barcode and return the number to me?

Tags: android, android-camera, offline, barcode-scanner

How i can perform barcode scanner in offline mode with using in camera as it can scan barcode and return the number to me?

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Answer (score 0):

You can do that BY using `Zxing` project that provides a standalone Barcode reader application which (via Android's intent mechanism ) can be called by other applications who wish to integrate Barcode scanning.

The **Codes** for `Zxing` project are:

**IntentIntegrator class:**

```
        /*
     * Copyright 2009 ZXing authors
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

     package com.google.zxing.integration.android;

     import java.util.Arrays;
     import java.util.Collection;
     import java.util.Collections;
     import java.util.HashMap;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Map;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.app.AlertDialog;
     import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
     import android.content.DialogInterface;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
     import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * <p>A utility class which helps ease integration with Barcode Scanner via {@link     Intent}s. This is a simple
     * way to invoke barcode scanning and receive the result, without any need to integrate, modify, or learn the
     * project's source code.</p>
     *
     * <h2>Initiating a barcode scan</h2>
     *
     * <p>To integrate, create an instance of {@code IntentIntegrator} and call {@link #initiateScan()} and wait
     * for the result in your app.</p>
     *
     * <p>It does require that the Barcode Scanner (or work-alike) application is installed. The
     * {@link #initiateScan()} method will prompt the user to download the application, if needed.</p>
     *
     * <p>There are a few steps to using this integration. First, your {@link Activity} must implement
     * the method {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} and include a line of code like this:</p>
     *
     * <pre>{@code
     * public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     *   IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
     *   if (scanResult != null) {
     *     // handle scan result
     *   }
     *   // else continue with any other code you need in the method
     *   ...
     * }
     * }</pre>
     *
     * <p>This is where you will handle a scan result.</p>
     *
     * <p>Second, just call this in response to a user action somewhere to begin the scan process:</p>
     *
     * <pre>{@code
     * IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
     * integrator.initiateScan();
     * }</pre>
     *
     * <p>Note that {@link #initiateScan()} returns an {@link AlertDialog} which is non-null if the
     * user was prompted to download the application. This lets the calling app potentially manage the dialog.
     * In particular, ideally, the app dismisses the dialog if it's still active in its {@link Activity#onPause()}
     * method.</p>
     *
     * <p>You can use {@link #setTitle(String)} to customize the title of this download prompt dialog (or, use
     * {@link #setTitleByID(int)} to set the title by string resource ID.) Likewise, the prompt message, and
     * yes/no button labels can be changed.</p>
     *
     * <p>Finally, you can use {@link #addExtra(String, Object)} to add more parameters to the Intent used
     * to invoke the scanner. This can be used to set additional options not directly exposed by this
     * simplified API.</p>
     *
     * <p>By default, this will only allow applications that are known to respond to this intent correctly
     * do so. The apps that are allowed to response can be set with {@link #setTargetApplications(List)}.
     * For example, set to {@link #TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY} to only target the Barcode Scanner app itself.</p>
     *
     * <h2>Sharing text via barcode</h2>
     *
     * <p>To share text, encoded as a QR Code on-screen, similarly, see {@link #shareText(CharSequence)}.</p>
     *
     * <p>Some code, particularly download integration, was contributed from the Anobiit application.</p>
     *
     * <h2>Enabling experimental barcode formats</h2>
     *
     * <p>Some formats are not enabled by default even when scanning with {@link #ALL_CODE_TYPES}, such as
     * PDF417. Use {@link #initiateScan(java.util.Collection)} with
     * a collection containing the names of formats to scan for explicitly, like "PDF_417", to use such
     * formats.</p>
     *
     * @author Sean Owen
     * @author Fred Lin
     * @author Isaac Potoczny-Jones
     * @author Brad Drehmer
     * @author gcstang
     */
    public class IntentIntegrator {

          public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000c0de; // Only use bottom 16 bits
          private static final String TAG = IntentIntegrator.class.getSimpleName();

          public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
          public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE =
              "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
          public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
          public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";

          private static final String BS_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
          private static final String BSPLUS_PACKAGE = "com.srowen.bs.android";

          // supported barcode formats
          public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");
          public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES =
              list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128",
                   "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");
          public static final Collection<String> QR_CODE_TYPES = Collections.singleton("QR_CODE");
          public static final Collection<String> DATA_MATRIX_TYPES = Collections.singleton("DATA_MATRIX");

          public static final Collection<String> ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;

          public static final List<String> TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY = Collections.singletonList(BS_PACKAGE);
          public static final List<String> TARGET_ALL_KNOWN = list(
                  BS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner
                  BSPLUS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner+
                  BSPLUS_PACKAGE + ".simple" // Barcode Scanner+ Simple
                  // What else supports this intent?
              );

          private final Activity activity;
          private String title;
          private String message;
          private String buttonYes;
          private String buttonNo;
          private List<String> targetApplications;
          private final Map<String,Object> moreExtras;

          public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
            message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
            buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
            buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
            targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
            moreExtras = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
          }

          public String getTitle() {
            return title;
          }

          public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
          }

          public void setTitleByID(int titleID) {
            title = activity.getString(titleID);
          }

          public String getMessage() {
            return message;
          }

          public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
          }

          public void setMessageByID(int messageID) {
            message = activity.getString(messageID);
          }

          public String getButtonYes() {
            return buttonYes;
          }

          public void setButtonYes(String buttonYes) {
            this.buttonYes = buttonYes;
          }

          public void setButtonYesByID(int buttonYesID) {
            buttonYes = activity.getString(buttonYesID);
          }

          public String getButtonNo() {
            return buttonNo;
          }

          public void setButtonNo(String buttonNo) {
            this.buttonNo = buttonNo;
          }

          public void setButtonNoByID(int buttonNoID) {
            buttonNo = activity.getString(buttonNoID);
          }

          public Collection<String> getTargetApplications() {
            return targetApplications;
          }

          public final void setTargetApplications(List<String> targetApplications) {
            if (targetApplications.isEmpty()) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("No target applications");
            }
            this.targetApplications = targetApplications;
          }

          public void setSingleTargetApplication(String targetApplication) {
            this.targetApplications = Collections.singletonList(targetApplication);
          }

          public Map<String,?> getMoreExtras() {
            return moreExtras;
          }

          public final void addExtra(String key, Object value) {
            moreExtras.put(key, value);
          }

          /**
           * Initiates a scan for all known barcode types.
           */
          public final AlertDialog initiateScan() {
            return initiateScan(ALL_CODE_TYPES);
          }

          /**
           * Initiates a scan only for a certain set of barcode types, given as strings corresponding
           * to their names in ZXing's {@code BarcodeFormat} class like "UPC_A". You can supply constants
           * like {@link #PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES} for example.
           *
           * @return the {@link AlertDialog} that was shown to the user prompting them to download the app
           *   if a prompt was needed, or null otherwise
           */
          public final AlertDialog initiateScan(Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormats) {
            Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
            intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

            // check which types of codes to scan for
            if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
              // set the desired barcode types
              StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
              for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
                if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
                  joinedByComma.append(',');
                }
                joinedByComma.append(format);
              }
              intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
            }

            String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
            if (targetAppPackage == null) {
              return showDownloadDialog();
            }
            intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
            intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
            startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
            return null;
          }

          /**
           * Start an activity.<br>
           * This method is defined to allow different methods of activity starting for
           * newer versions of Android and for compatibility library.
           *
           * @param intent Intent to start.
           * @param code Request code for the activity
           * @see android.app.Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
           * @see android.app.Fragment#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
           */
          protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
          }

          private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
            PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if (availableApps != null) {
              for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
                String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
                if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
                  return packageName;
                }
              }
            }
            return null;
          }

          private AlertDialog showDownloadDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
            downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
            downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String packageName = targetApplications.get(0);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                  activity.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                  // Hmm, market is not installed
                  Log.w(TAG, "Google Play is not installed; cannot install " + packageName);
                }
              }
            });
            downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
            });
            return downloadDialog.show();
          }


          /**
           * <p>Call this from your {@link Activity}'s
           * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} method.</p>
           *
           * @return null if the event handled here was not related to this class, or
           *  else an {@link IntentResult} containing the result of the scan. If the user cancelled scanning,
           *  the fields will be null.
           */
          public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
                int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
                Integer orientation = intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? null : intentOrientation;
                String errorCorrectionLevel = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");
                return new IntentResult(contents,
                                        formatName,
                                        rawBytes,
                                        orientation,
                                        errorCorrectionLevel);
              }
              return new IntentResult();
            }
            return null;
          }


          /**
           * Defaults to type "TEXT_TYPE".
           * @see #shareText(CharSequence, CharSequence)
           */
          public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text) {
            return shareText(text, "TEXT_TYPE");
          }

          /**
           * Shares the given text by encoding it as a barcode, such that another user can
           * scan the text off the screen of the device.
           *
           * @param text the text string to encode as a barcode
           * @param type type of data to encode. See {@code com.google.zxing.client.android.Contents.Type} constants.
           * @return the {@link AlertDialog} that was shown to the user prompting them to download the app
           *   if a prompt was needed, or null otherwise
           */
          public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text, CharSequence type) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setAction(BS_PACKAGE + ".ENCODE");
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
            String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
            if (targetAppPackage == null) {
              return showDownloadDialog();
            }
            intent.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            attachMoreExtras(intent);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            return null;
          }

          private static List<String> list(String... values) {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values));
          }

          private void attachMoreExtras(Intent intent) {
            for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : moreExtras.entrySet()) {
              String key = entry.getKey();
              Object value = entry.getValue();
              // Kind of hacky
              if (value instanceof Integer) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (Integer) value);
              } else if (value instanceof Long) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (Long) value);
              } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (Boolean) value);
              } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (Double) value);
              } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (Float) value);
              } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (Bundle) value);
              } else {
                intent.putExtra(key, value.toString());
              }
            }
          }

        }
```

**IntentResult class:**

```
            /*
         * Copyright 2009 ZXing authors
         *
         * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
         * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
         * You may obtain a copy of the License at
         *
         *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
         *
         * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
         * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
         * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
         * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
         * limitations under the License.
         */

        package com.google.zxing.integration.android;

        /**
         * <p>Encapsulates the result of a barcode scan invoked through {@link IntentIntegrator}.</p>
         *
         * @author Sean Owen
         */
        public final class IntentResult {

          private final String contents;
          private final String formatName;
          private final byte[] rawBytes;
          private final Integer orientation;
          private final String errorCorrectionLevel;

          IntentResult() {
            this(null, null, null, null, null);
          }

          IntentResult(String contents,
                       String formatName,
                       byte[] rawBytes,
                       Integer orientation,
                       String errorCorrectionLevel) {
            this.contents = contents;
            this.formatName = formatName;
            this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
            this.orientation = orientation;
            this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
          }

          /**
           * @return raw content of barcode
           */
          public String getContents() {
            return contents;
          }

          /**
           * @return name of format, like "QR_CODE", "UPC_A". See {@code BarcodeFormat} for more format names.
           */
          public String getFormatName() {
            return formatName;
          }

          /**
           * @return raw bytes of the barcode content, if applicable, or null otherwise
           */
          public byte[] getRawBytes() {
            return rawBytes;
          }

          /**
           * @return rotation of the image, in degrees, which resulted in a successful scan. May be null.
           */
          public Integer getOrientation() {
            return orientation;
          }

          /**
           * @return name of the error correction level used in the barcode, if applicable
           */
          public String getErrorCorrectionLevel() {
            return errorCorrectionLevel;
          }

          @Override
          public String toString() {
            StringBuilder dialogText = new StringBuilder(100);
            dialogText.append("Format: ").append(formatName).append('\n');
            dialogText.append("Contents: ").append(contents).append('\n');
            int rawBytesLength = rawBytes == null ? 0 : rawBytes.length;
            dialogText.append("Raw bytes: (").append(rawBytesLength).append(" bytes)\n");
            dialogText.append("Orientation: ").append(orientation).append('\n');
            dialogText.append("EC level: ").append(errorCorrectionLevel).append('\n');
            return dialogText.toString();
          }

        }
```

**To call `Zxing` in desired Activity:**

```
         //instantiate ZXing integration class
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            //start scanning
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

**To get scanning result by:**

```
if (scanningResult != null) {
    //get content from Intent Result
    String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
    //get format name of data scanned
    String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
}
```

For more you can see This [zxing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Zxing library:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

There is also a embedded version:

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

With add the scanner activity to your Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and open it with

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Scan.ACTION);
    intent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
    //Add any optional extras to pass
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.MODE, Intents.Scan.ONE_D_MODE);
    //Launch
    startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and grab the results with

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SCAN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```